# How to improve a SQL Server table insertion performance by primary key or non-clustered index with uniqueness constraint?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, composite-primary-key

In order to control the duplicate rows in a SQL Server table, which approach will have the better performance for insert times in high loads?

1. Create a primary key constraint on a column that should have a unique value in the table (type of column is `varchar(100)` and the possible value is like `g_12546987456_13-9`. It means a composite primary key and no specific character orders)
2. Create a numeric and auto-incremented primary key and set a non-clustered index with uniqueness constraint on the string column (`g_12546987456_13-9`)

Comment: You can test this, can't you? We can't [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) for you.

Comment: It depends. If you have a very small number of columns then on average the cost of writing to two indexes may exceed to cost of the page splits from having a clustering key that is not ever increasing. If you have a large number of other columns then the page splits will be more expensive and may outweigh the cost of writing to an additional index. As Stu says, race your horses

Comment: @Stu I've asked this question because testing with a small table size is easy, but I'm worried about the future, when the size of the table becomes bigger ( more than 500 million rows).

Comment: Comment still applies, in fact even more so. Create your own test data in a dev envorinment using a cartesian join to simulate a large table, then race.

Comment: Your question betrays a common misconception/omission: a primary key constraint is always implicitly backed by a unique index, but that index need not be the clustered index. It will be the clustered index by default, but that can be overridden. From the way you've phrased things, you seem to assume a primary key necessarily means a clustered primary key, but clustering the table on an auto-increment value and using a non-clustered primary key is largely equivalent to your option 2 while still having a PK.

Comment: Also note that *either* option will cause attempted duplicate inserts to fail, essentially meaning the I/O for those attempts is "wasted". Instead of wondering which will have better performance if lots of duplicates occur, a much better question is how to prevent this from happening in the first place. Of course this isn't always possible, but where it is it beats worrying about what indexing strategy best supports catching duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you have to be vigilant about, when creating these Alpha-Numeric Primary keys, you have to make sure that your Alpha-Numeric values are Incremental.

The first option you have mentioned with Random values, will most certainly impact the performance massively. Because of the random Primary Key, it will end up inserting new rows on the existing data pages, thus pushing records down and ending up with Page splits - Very bad for SQL Server Performance. (One of the main reason why GUID is not a good candidate for a Primary Key and MS had to introduced sequential GUID).

I would suggest make use of SQL Server Sequence Object to Auto-Increment values and with your desired Alphabets but still make sure the new values are sequential and incremental.